# i am getting rinkeby error while running my deploy_and_create.py in brownie python

Tags: web3.py, nft, rinkeby, brownie, solidity-0.6.x

PS E:\NFT-DEMO> brownie run scripts/deploy_and_create.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftDemoProject is the active project.
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_*main*_.py", line 64, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 52, in connect
uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This states that you have not set the environment variable. Using brownie you can easily do that by creating a file named **.env** inside the brownie project and there you can export your variable as

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now brownie will place this variable to get the infura instance

Comment: yes i have did it

Comment: but still iam getting the same error

Comment: Do you have brownie-config.yaml file?

Comment: If you don't then create it and make sure have this content in it
```dotenv: .env```

Comment: yes i have made a .env file and I put my private key and infura project id in it but still the same error persist

Comment: yes i have brownie config.yml file now what to do with it?

Comment: ```dotenv: .env```
add this to the brownie-config.yaml 
And make sure the file is named "brownie-config.yaml" exactly

Comment: after doing that i am getting:

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCollectible' from 'scripts.helpful_scripts' (E:\NFT-DEMO\scripts\helpful_scripts.py)
PS E:\NFT-DEMO> 
this error

Comment: Only naming the file as SimpleCollectible.sol won't work. Make sure that inside the file it is written as
```contract SimpleCollectible {... ```
And check for spelling mistake as it is case sensitive

Comment: ya nikhil but my all spellings are correct and I've written it as contract SimpleCollectible

Comment: Have you imported like so
```from brownie import SimpleCollectible```
Also if this is right then please edit your question and add the code of helpful_scripts

Comment: from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, SimpleCollectible

this is what i have written

Comment: No we have to import contracts from brownie and not from the script itself

Comment: from brownie import SimpleCollectible..... i have written this now 
and getting this error

File ".\scripts\deploy_and_create.py", line 2, in <module>
    from brownie import Simplecollectible
ImportError: cannot import name 'Simplecollectible' from 'brownie' (C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\__init__.py)

Comment: ohh done now i am able to render my nft thank you so much Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

This is your error.

It says you have not set the environment variable.

You must set the environment variable.

Comment: how to set environment variable